# how to add function SelectHandler in googlechart api

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, charts, google-visualization

I have been trying to add a clickable link in a stacked bar chart. I can't find any solution at all. can anyone help me, please. What I want is when I click the data, it will go to the link based on data clicked

[Image of the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5lZI.png)

I am using this [Googlechart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#stacked-bar-charts)

Here is the code:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
         'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
        ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
        ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
      ]);

      var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true
      };
```

This is what i added. it only goes to the same link for every data.. i want to put each of them different link

```
function selectHandler() {
          var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[1];
          if (selectedItem) {
            var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 1);
            alert('The user selected ' + topping);
          }
        }
 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the row selected, the selection property also includes the column...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General', 'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
    ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
    ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 3},
    bar: {groupWidth: '75%'},
    isStacked: true
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
  function selectHandler() {
    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection();
    if (selectedItem.length > 0) {
      var value = data.getValue(selectedItem[0].row, selectedItem[0].column);
      console.log('The user selected ' + data.getColumnLabel(selectedItem[0].column) + ': ' + value);
    }
  }

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```